# C# coordinates are missing dot "." after degree value when parse to double

Tags: c#, double, coordinates

*Can someone more smarter than me take look at this code, after "double.TryParse(coordinates[0], out double lat" coordinates are missing dot "." after degree value. And I do not have any idea how to solve this.*

Soluton: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture did the trick with this problem.

```
string dataInput = "44.807222 14.000000, 44.759167 14.035556, 44.755000 14.011944, 44.794167 13.983333;44.800000 13.685278, 44.707222 13.733333, 44.685278 13.605833, 44.793889 13.496111;";

// Split on semicolon to get individual polygons
string[] polygonStrings = dataInput.Split(';');

// Create a list to store GMapPolygons
List<GMapPolygon> polygons = new List<GMapPolygon>();

foreach (var polygonString in polygonStrings)
{
    // Split each polygon string on comma to get individual coordinates
    string[] coordStrings = polygonString.Trim().Split(',');

    // Create a list to store PointLatLng objects for each polygon
    List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();

    foreach (var coordString in coordStrings)
    {
        // Split each coordinate string on space to get latitude and longitude
        string[] coordinates = coordString.Trim().Split(' ');

        // Ensure there are two coordinates
        if (coordinates.Length == 2 && double.TryParse(coordinates[0], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double lat) && double.TryParse(coordinates[1], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double lon))
        {
            // Create a PointLatLng object and add it to the list of points
            points.Add(new PointLatLng(lat, lon));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error parsing coordinates: {coordString}");
        }
    }

    // Create Polygon
    GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(points, "ime");
    polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Blue));
    polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);

    // Add the polygon to the list
    polygons.Add(polygon);
}
```

Comment: I didn't check if that's the problem but try to include a defined culture for parsing the number, i.e. `double.TryParse(coordinates[0], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double lat)`. You might be using a wrong number format.

Comment: I have trayed using "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture", but it gives me comma instead a dot and coordinate for GMAP.Net needs a dot.

Comment: Eh, please defined what exactly you mean by "gives me comma". Check with a debugger what the actual parsed values are. Note that the values **shown** in the debugger are formatted with your local (i.e. Windows) number settings. `double` values don't have a dot or comma or whatever. They are floating point numbers. The dot or comma is used when representing these as a string. So I don't see how the `PointLatLng`  constructor "needs a dot" - it needs two correct floating point numbers.

Comment: Coordinate should look like this 43.976944 16.256111 but after parse it look like this 43,976944 16,256111 - this is what I mean it missing a dot, dot is replaced with comma. But if I change in Win settings decimal symbol to "." coordinate are shown correctly, it is not solution. I have even tried add custom culture info -> `CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); customCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."; ` but it did not work.

Comment: You are confusing a numeric value and its string representation. You parse the string to a double using `double.TryParse` with the correct format. When you then look at the `double` value in i.e. the debugger, it is converted back to a string for display. This conversion is done with the local windows culture settings, hence why you see the change when changing it. So it is actually working as expected.

Comment: It make sense. Then the problem is not in parse coordinate value but in a code around GMAP polygon ... well that sucks :( need to take look at that. Thank you!

Comment: OK, problem is not in GMAP polygon. Problem is somewhere in converting coords from string to double. My data are stored in string value and GMAP reads double value and I cannot figure out how to go around this.

Comment: Ok I have solved, do not ask how..I do not know tried for an 10th time add CultureInfo and this time works as a charm. `if (coordinates.Length == 2 &&
    double.TryParse(coordinates[0], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double lat) &&
    double.TryParse(coordinates[1], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double lon))
{
    // Create a PointLatLng object and add it to the list of points
    polygonPoints.Add(new PointLatLng(lat, lon));
}`